# Adding DataAnnotations to generated class in a separate EF project - using buddy classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using a multi-tier concept where I have my `EMDX` and entities in one project/library and my main application in another project where is the best place to the buddy classes so that I can attach "clean" display names to my model's fields.

I have created a partial class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ReportColumnMD))]
public partial class ReportColumn
{ }

public class ReportColumnMD
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string ColumnDescription { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Group Description")]
    public string GroupDescription { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Default State")]
    public Nullable<bool> DefaultState { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Enabled")]
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

in my application project. Everything compiles fine but the display names still are the original DB column names. Does this partial class need to reside in the EF project? Under the same namespace?

My preference would be to keep this in the application project.

Any suggestions or ideas?

**Update

I have moved the partial class to the EF project and changed the namespace. This works but I would still like to find a way to keep this in my application project.

***Update

I've basically taken the tact of creating a Metadata folder in my EF project and putting my data annotation buddy classes in there. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think that if the class isn't in the same namespace, it basically is another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have basically adopted the strategy as explained in the second update and given up on trying to keep the buddy classes in a separate project.